# How do I write regular expression for array of decimal values?

Tags: regex

I have the following array of decimal values and could you please help me in writing regular expression for validating them?

```
[456, 789]
[456.24, 789.24]
[456.24]
```

As you can see in the above 3 examples, the array contents will vary each time and values in them will sometimes be displayed with decimal places and sometimes as whole number and sometimes the array will have only one value. Also my regular expression should validate if the characters before decimal point is minimum of 3 digits and maximum of 5 digits.

I have written a regex like -

```
^\[(\d{3,5}\.)?\d+,\s(\d{3,5}\.)?\d+\]$
```

which works for array `[456.24, 78]` but not for `[456.24]`

Could you please help me in correcting the regex I have written.

Answer (score 1):

Adding whitespace for leeway, it is this

`\[\s*\d{3,5}(?:\.\d*)?(?:\s*,\s*\d{3,5}(?:\.\d*)?)*\s*\]`

Readable

```
 \[
 \s* 
 \d{3,5} 
 (?: \. \d* )?
 (?:
      \s* , \s* 
      \d{3,5} 
      (?: \. \d* )?
 )*
 \s* 
 \]
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely for a constant number of values, you should put a quantifier:

```
^\[\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*\]$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/pDQsA2/1)

Breakdown:

- `^\[` Match start of input then an immediate `[`
- `\d+` Match any number of digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Match an optional decimal part
- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group #2

  - `,\s*` Match a comma preceding optional whitespaces
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match a number, same as before
- `)*` Repeat as many as possible or zero time
- `\]$` Match `]` and end of string

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` instead could make things a whole lot easier.

```
(?:[[\]]|,\s*)
```

This splits on square brackets or comma followed by an optional? space and returns an array like

```
[0] => 
[1] => 456.24
[2] => 789.24
[3] =>
```

Note: The first and the last element is empty because we also split on the square brackets.
If you don't like that you can simply trim/remove the brackets first or use another regex to select everything between two square brackets, e.g. `\[([^\][]*?)\]` (here in group `\1`)